# How Nativescript works?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, nativescript

As I understand it uses Javascript engines to run javascript code on android/ios platform?

Also android/ios APIs (java, objective C) can be called with Nativescript javascript code, like this:

-On build Nativescript create metadata of all android/ios APIs
-And leter when some api is called from javascript it looks for specific metadata and Nativescript run C++ to invoke android/ios API

Question is am I right? Feel free to correct me and add some additional things to understand this better?

Comment: http://developer.telerik.com/featured/nativescript-works/ http://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/android/overview

Comment: I already chacked it.... It is little bit confusing

Comment: You already have a better understanding than most starting out :) judging from your question.

Comment: Understand that it's a bit confusing :) it's not the simplest stuff to understand that's for sure. I still don't understand all of the layers involved but your question already states the basics of how it works.

Comment: I read few articles about it, and I am not sure did I understand it good. It amaze me how it is easy to write mob app with web dev skills. So I would like to understand how they accomplish that.

Comment: The best place to get a deep understanding is the source code, it's all open source so dig in :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Android:**

Build-time all referenced `classes.jar`s (those coming from plugins, support libraries, etc.) as well as the `android.jar` SDK are parsed and binary metadata is written in 3 main chunks.

On app startup the first-level namespaces (`android`, `com`) are attached to the global scope in JavaScript. Then at any moment, while the app is running, when anything like `android.a.b.c` is accessed the metadata chunks are read, built, javascript callbacks attached to the objects, and cached in the virtual machine, so that consecutive access to any members of that namespace is readily available.

Thanks to the metadata and callbacks that are attached to objects, the runtime knows when to create a new Java counterpart of an object (e.g. when you write 'new java.lang.Object()' in JavaScript) and link the JS instance with the one in Java world, this helps syncing the two Garbage Collectors (that of v8 and that of the android virtual machine on the Android device *(dalvik/arm)*)

http://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/android/advanced-topics/execution-flow

Comment: So JS know how to access this `android.a.b.c` because it is added to global scope of V8 when app is started, also callbacks that are attached to that object returns data to JS, am I right?